# problems with ./configure for libtorrent on linux

Tags: linux, boost, installation, configure, libtorrent

Hell I have been having an extremely tough time installing libtorrent and am unsure what the problems are. I have seen plenty similar errors online but the solutions were not helpful and I am pretty sure the error message is just too vague for comparison.

When I run ./configure I get

**

```
Building libtorrent-rasterbar 0.16.5

Checking for a C/C++ compiler to use:
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking whether gcc and cc understand -c and -o together... yes
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking whether g++ understands -c and -o together... yes
.
..
.
Checking for boost libraries:
checking for boostlib >= 1.36... yes
checking whether the Boost::System library is available... yes
configure: error: Boost.System library not found. Try using --with-boost-system=lib
```

**

I then use the suggestion and the difference is that the bottom says

**

```
Checking for boost libraries:
checking for boostlib >= 1.36... yes
checking whether the Boost::System library is available... yes
checking for exit in -llib... no
checking for exit in -lboost_system-lib... no
configure: error: Could not link against boost_system-lib !
```

**

the config.log file has an error

**

```
configure:16572: result: no
configure:16537: checking for exit in -lboost_system-lib
configure:16562: gcc -o conftest -lpthread -g -O2 -fvisibility=hidden  -I/usr/include  -L/usr/lib conftest.c -lboost_system-lib  -lpthread   >&5
conftest.c:33: warning: conflicting types for built-in function 'exit'
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_system-lib
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**

Any insight would be enormously appreciated

after installing

`apt-get install libboost-system-dev`

`apt-get install libboost-filesystem-dev libboost-thread-dev`

```
Checking features to be enabled:
checking whether encryption support should be enabled... yes
configure: encryption support: now checking for the OpenSSL library...
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking for openssl/ssl.h in /usr/local/ssl... no
checking for openssl/ssl.h in /usr/lib/ssl... no
checking for openssl/ssl.h in /usr/ssl... no
checking for openssl/ssl.h in /usr/pkg... no
checking for openssl/ssl.h in /usr/local... no
checking for openssl/ssl.h in /usr... no
checking whether compiling and linking against OpenSSL works... no
configure: error: OpenSSL library not found. Try using --with-openssl=DIR or disabling encryption at all.
```

Comment: check my answer for openssl

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to install libboost-system.

If you are using Debian/Ubuntu, use apt-get as follows.

```
$ apt-get install libboost-system-dev
```

You may also need to install ...

```
$ apt-get install libboost-filesystem-dev libboost-thread-dev
```

Comment: hmmmm now I get the error----------

checking whether compiling and linking against OpenSSL works... no
configure: error: OpenSSL library not found. Try using --with-openssl=DIR or disabling encryption at all.

Answer (score 4):

The [easiest way](https://coderwall.com/p/muvnow) to install all the dependencies is with apt-get.

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python-libtorrent
```

Comment: Thanks saved a ton of time

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a bit old, but to solve your OpenSSL problem you need to install the OpenSSL libraries with `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`.

Answer (score 2):

For CentOS users, you will want to install boost-devel.

```
# yum install boost-devel
```

But I still got the same error. Just want to point out one more thing, the CentOS 6.4 I work with had an old gcc compiler:

```
# g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Installing a newer version of gcc helped me to get rid of that particular error. I used **g++ (GCC) 4.8.2** version and this time calling the following command worked:

```
# ./configure --with-boost-libdir=/usr/lib64
```

After this point you might still run into not finding openssl headers like the OP posted here, [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/371901/openssl-missing-during-configure-how-to-fix) will help to overcome the error. You may have to install openssl-devel (for CentOS) or libssl-dev (for Debian), or you can run with

```
# ./configure --with-boost-libdir=/usr/lib64 --without-ssl
```

If you have openssl headers installed in your system, you don't need to use --with-openssl flag, or at least I didn't need to use it.

Although this is old post, hope it will help someone else like me.

Comment: really helped @Zobayer Hasan :)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid OpenSSL issues you can build "libtorrent-rasterbar" disabling OpenSSL encryption.

For instance:

```
./configure --disable-debug --disable-encryption --prefix=/opt/libtorrent-rasterbar
```

And then "make" + "make install"

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer didn't work for me. What did work was editing the `configure` script file and removing those lines from it:

```
if test -z "$BOOST_SYSTEM_LIB"; then :
  as_fn_error $? "Boost.System library not found. Try using --with-boost-system=lib" "$LINENO" 5
fi
```

Those lines seemed to check that the BOOST_SYSTEM_LIB environment variable exists and is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

For Arch users (ex. Manjaro) install the boost pkg from pacman. Search for "boost" and install from Official Repo(extra).